# Prevent Sign in with google button flickering while loading when centered vertically (Google GSI)

Tags: google-signin

**Currently when I use the new API for the personalised sign in with google button, when the button is centered vertically in a flex container, when it is loading it flickers up and down.**

Example code is shown below, just in html and css for simplicity, however building this in react - same thing happens.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css" type="text/css"
  ></link>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>
    <script src="./script.js"></script>
    <div
      id="g_id_onload"
      data-client_id="920029725372-e913v434vc2hfbb6cfkrs7qhiuvuita6.apps.googleusercontent.com"
      data-callback="handleCredentialResponse"
    ></div>
    <div class="button-wrapper">
      <div class="g_id_signin" data-type="standard"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Google Sans";
  src: url("https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/googlesans/v14/4UabrENHsxJlGDuGo1OIlLU94YtzCwM.ttf")
    format("truetype");
}

.button-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Sorta wish google would allow for custom buttons or at least an API so that issues like this could be avoided instead of forcing devs to use an `<iframe/>`, also the new API isn't awesomely documented (I'm assuming because of how new it is but hopefully this will get better with time.

Comment: You can't really do much about the button flickering, but I stopped the entire page from flickering by adding a min-height to the button's container, so that it won't resize every time it re-renders.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For some reason, Google created two div's to house identical buttons. The second, with the iframe, replaces the first when the proper font loads. The order in which the css is modified by Google means that no matter how you try to correct the flash with pure css, it will still show up in some way. I went so far as to overlay the div's using position:absolute but the margin gets modified on the first div so it still shifts up before vanishing.

The only thing I found to work is hide one of the div's permanently. Either way works, the difference is the button font. This one lets the iframe only version load:

```
.g_id_signin > div > div:first-child{
  display: none;
}
```

This one loads the initial div only, so the font is off, but it shows up faster and the auth flow still works:

```
.g_id_signin > div > div:last-child{
  display: none;
}
```

You could probably catch and handle the flicker via javascript, but I'm not spending that much time on this. I'll use this css fix until Google updates their code.

Comment: Only the first snippet worked for me. 

The flickering in my case seemed to be as result of the first version to be loaded being a generic 'Sign in with Google', which is then replaced by a 'Sign in as Dave / dave@davesdomain.com' button.

So with the first version, I now just get a short delay before then seeing the personalized version.

As an aside I also had to apply "color-scheme: normal" to the iframe to avoid a white box appearing around the button.

Comment: I don't think it works for me. My CSS seems to not able to reach inside the iframe elements.

Comment: First one fixes the size flicker, but it's not visible at the beginning and flickers on. Second one did not work at all for me.

Comment: The first snippet works well, though there is a delay as the iframe loads in (sometimes a fairly long one, at that). The second snippet didn't work—it's possible Google has changed its code since this answer was written. Google's script now seems to set inline styles, so if you want to hide the iframe'd button, you need to do something like this:


```css
.g_id_signin iframe { display: none !important; }
```

I find I prefer this option as the button renders much more quickly.

Answer (score 6):

The best solution I found is to wrap the Sign In with Google button in a div and make that div's height 44px i.e. the height of the button. That way as the button loads additional content, it won't move anything up and down.
As the old generic sign in with google button disappears and new sign in with name and email appears, that unloading and loading seems to cause the flicker.

```
.GoogleLoginButtonContainer {
    height: 44px;
    width: auto;
 }
```

Comment: This was a great workaround. Unfortunately, with users not logged in, they will see the font flicker assuming the site uses a different font than Google's default button font. And also, there will be a small flicker when the users are logged in. However, the flicker is simply the customized button loading rather than the size flickering.

Comment: While the native height of the Google button is indeed 44px, I have to set mine to 42px. There's some sort of padding in there that's screwing with a sibling's margin, which is set to Bootstrap's mt-2, which translates to 8px. Setting the container height to 44px, somehow makes the space between the button and its sibling too small. But setting it to 42px makes the margin space 8px. But only after the font-load, that normally causes a flicker. Before it loads, the margin space is too big (probably 10px). Oh, well...

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the flickering below the input field for typically an email address with next to it the button with the G icon added by Google, I added `style="height:0px"` to the `span` which shows the button. Here is a snippet:

```
<span class="g_id_signin noprint" title="Connect with Google" data-type="icon" data-shape="circle" data-theme="outline" data-text="signup_with" data-size="medium" data-locale="en" style="height:0px"></span>
```

The button still flickers when the code in Javascript by Google has added the `iframe` with another identical button. The delay is also a problem. I'd like to disable the button, show it in gray, until everything is ready.

With a full button showing text, I haven't found a way to avoid the redrawing of the text after the font is loaded.